# Como ligar um link a um objeto? Servlet

Tags: java, html, servlet

Foi feita uma proposta de solução em servlet, tenho um formulário elaborado em html, salvo os dados em um banco de dados, pego esses dados e disponho em uma tabela html, nessa tabela tem os atributos do objeto pessoa, um dos valores dessas colunas é um link, quando o usuário clicar nesse link tenho que apagar a pessoa correspondente a essa linha, a duvida é: como ligo uma pessoa com um link? Segue uma imagem da tabela. Excluir é um link para excluir a pessoa, mas é um link que não direciona a lugar algum, meramente ilustrativo, para ajudar na abstração... 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: vc precisa criar um servlet novo ou um método, ele vai receber o id da pessoa e excluir. na listagem  é necessário passar o id no link.

Comment: Pode colcoar o código da listagem?

Comment: @HeloísaAlves tem  que ser em uma página html não pode ser em uma página jsp? Com uma jsp ia dar para usar jtsl e facilitar tudo.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui está o código construído ele é bem simples,possui duas  páginas JSP e um Servlet, aqui uso o padrão DAO , temos a classe `User` que representa o nosso objeto "usuário" , a classe `UserDAO` que faz a ponte entre o banco e a aplicação,finalmente, temos  a classe `DbUtil` que cria a conexão através dos dados inseridos no arquivo `db.proprerties`.
 Para poder usá-lo você deve usar dentro do diretorio lib do seu projeto web  os seguintes arquivos:
 `jtsl.jar` junto com `standart.jar` 
eu usei o banco de dados PostgreSQL, e por isso usei o arquivo 
`postgresql-9.4-1202.jdbc4.jar` se você usa o MySQL ou outro banco ,basta apenas trocar o arquivo(driver de conexão) para ficar de acordo com o seu banco.
 Todo o processo trabalha com controle de sessão e com o uso da classe RequestDispatcher que é usado dentro do único servlet  da aplicação `UserController`.
 Antes de mais nada gostaria de dizer que abordei apenas o necessário para obter sua resposta com o código , coisas interessantes como tratamento de erros,para o caso de o "usuario" inserir uma string para o CPF  eu deixei em segunda mão, Mas isso você pode fazer com tranquilidade,Para testar o codigo suponha que o usuário vai digitar tudo como o esperado!!
Aqui esta a paginá JSP que insere o seu link para deletar os usuários:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <link type="text/css"
              href="css/estilo.css"rel="stylesheet" />
<title>Todos Usuários</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border=1>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>CPF</th>
                <th>Nome</th>               
                <th>Sexo</th>
                <th>Salário</th>
                <th colspan=2>Ação</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.CPF}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.nome}" /></td>                         
                    <td><c:out value="${user.sexo}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.salario}" /></td>  

                    <td><a href="UserController?action=delete&CPF=<c:out value="${user.CPF}"/>">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p><a href="UserController?action=insert">Adicionar novo  Usuário</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Você pode baixar o projeto completo no [GITHUB](https://github.com/WellingtonLins/Projeto_MeuCrud), para poder analisar mais detalhadamente